# Cannot import SqlJS into react: import does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, sqlite, reactjs

I'm trying to incorporate the [SQLjs emscriptem port](https://kripken.github.io/sql.js/GUI/) of SQLite into react. Basic usage of the sql.js package works fine as shown below:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
     table { border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; }
     table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; text-align:left; font-family:Arial,Helvetica}
     th { color:white;background-color:green}
     th, td { padding:4px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://kripken.github.io/sql.js/js/sql.js"></script>
    <h1>SQL Demo</h1>
    <div id="results">
    </div>

    
    <script>
     //Create the database
     var db = new SQL.Database();
     // Run a query without reading the results
     db.run("CREATE TABLE employees (id integer, name varchar(50), salary float);");
     // Insert two rows: (1,111) and (2,222)
     db.run("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (?,?,?), (?,?,?), (?,?,?)", [1,'will',111.55, 2,'sam', 222.25, 3,'mary', 333.99]);

     // Prepare a statement
     var stmt = db.prepare("SELECT id, name, salary, round(salary) AS rounded_salary FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC");
     stmt.getAsObject({$start:1, $end:4}); // {col1:1, col2:111}

     // Bind new values
     stmt.bind({$start:1, $end:2});
     var output = '<table>';
     output += '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Salary</th><th>Rounded salary</th></tr><tbody>';
     while(stmt.step()) { //
       var row = stmt.getAsObject();
       // [...] do something with the row of result
       
       output += '<tr><td>' + row.id + '</td><td>' + row.name + '</td><td>$' + row.salary + '</td><td>$' + row.rounded_salary + '.00</td>';
       output += '</tr>';
     }
     output += '</tbody></table>';
     var elem = document.getElementById('results');
     elem.innerHTML = output;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, when I use `create-react-app` to create a basic app, use `npm install sqljs --save` to add the module and use it, I cannot access the library. I don't understand exactly why this doesn't work.  It seems like it should-- I was able, for instance, to use the CodeMirror package `react-codemirror` in this way with no issues.

Here's what I have. In my `App.js` I put :

`import SQLOutput from './SQLOutput';`

and then in `SQLOutput.js` I put:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as SQL from 'sqljs';

class SQLOutput extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.db = new SQL.Database();
  }
}

export default SQLOutput;
```

Eventually the plan is to do the querying you saw in the first html file, but in this react component, and have it render the results somewhere.

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to access the SQL.Database object as a constructor. React or ES6 complains `Uncaught TypeError: SQL.Database is not a constructor`.  In fact, the SQL object that you see in the debugger under react differs considerably from the global object injected in the simple version at the top of this post.

Is it impossible to use an older library like sqljs inside react this way?  As a dumb alternative, I also just tried to use it via my index.html file as a plain old script load, and that also doesn't work. Maybe something to do with the way `create-react-app` is packaging things up?

Any pointers appreciated for this react noob.

My package.json contains:

```
{
  "name": "react-sqljs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-codemirror": "^0.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "sqljs": "0.0.0-6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: how about `import SQL from 'sqljs';`?

Comment: yup, tried that, no luck there. If you do that you get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: _sqljs2.default.Database is not a constructor`

Answer (score 0):

check out this example: https://github.com/sql-js/react-sqljs-demo/blob/master/src/App.js

```
import initSqlJs from "sql.js";
```